# How to squeeze all but one torch dims?

Tags: python, pytorch

[`torch.squeeze`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.squeeze.html) can convert the shape of a tensor to not have dimensions of size 1.

I want to squeeze my tensor in all dimensions but one (in this example, not squeeze `dim=0`).

All I can see in the doc is

> dim (int, optional) – if given, the input will be squeezed only in
> this dimension

I want the opposite:

```
t = torch.zeros(5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1)

squeezed = torch.magic_squeeze(keep_dim=3)

assert squeezed == (5, 6, 1, 7)
```

Can this be done?

Answer (score 3):

Reshape will let you accomplish what you want to do:

```
import torch

t = torch.zeros(5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1)
t = t.reshape((5, 6, 1, 7))
>>> torch.Size([5, 6, 1, 7])
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just squeeze and add a dimension with `unsqueeze()`:

```
import torch

t = torch.zeros(5, 1, 6, 1, 7, 1)
squeezed = t.squeeze().unsqueeze(2)
print(squeezed.shape)
>>> torch.Size([5, 6, 1, 7])
```

Comment: Thanks, I was looking for something more built in :)